# .Net 4.5.x - custom TimeSpan formatting with optional sections?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, format, timespan

I have a data processing system which returns a number of variables as Timespan. The user can configure how they wish to see this output by supplying a format string, which I then apply to the timespan.

e.g. User sets format to d\,\ h:mm:ss, output is 0, 0:00:00 (for zero).

I'd like to make it possible for the system to automatically skip days or hours if they're zero.

i.e. User sets format [d\, ][h:]mm:\ss and gets 00:00 to 59:59 for less than an hour, then 1:00:00 to 23:59:59 for less than a day, then 1, 00:00:00 to x, nn:nn:nn for anything greater, where x= number of days.

The built-in timespan doesn't offer the "optional" sections in square brackets.

Is there an easy way to achieve this I'm not seeing, or do I need to write my own version of the TimeSpan formatter?

Comment: C# or Vb? You have both tags

Comment: Either/or, my code is in VB but a c# solution would be just as useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly elegant, but I did something like this:

```
    Dim fmt As String
    fmt = If(thisTimespan >= TimeSpan.FromDays(1), "d\d\-\ h\:mm\:ss\.fff", "h\:mm\:ss\.fff")
```

You could easily expand this to eliminate unneeded hours as well.

Comment: This would be OK if the format was fixed in the code - but the user can configure it. e.g. they might not want the comma after the number of days; they may never want to show the number of days...

Comment: You can use whatever source for the formatting you'd like. You could break out the bracketed sections (user specified) in your example and add them to the final formatting string (without the brackets) based on the value of the timespan.